# Array name in brackets

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, syntax, operators

Could you explain the magic behind `(1+3)[a]` indexing as in the following code? ([taken from here](https://www.toptal.com/c-plus-plus/interview-questions))

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::cout << (1 + 3)[a] - a[0] + (a + 1)[2];
}
```

Is this indexing some relic of C language? I thought indexing operator `[]` cannot take an array in it. Would the same work for e.g. `std::vector`?

Comment: *"Would the same work for e.g. std::vector"* - Do you really need to ask like this? I'd have expected you to try first, at least.

Comment: Yes this is like a 'a++' but in this case is based to an index from vector in your example : (4 + 1)[a];  you must use (1) + index of the vector but you can't use (4 + 2)[a] this will give you a error warn ... sorry for my english :(.